# ShareKit and TwitPic

Tags: iphone, twitpic, sharekit

Heya has anyone tried out sharekit www.getsharekit.com

Im looking for a simple plug n play way to get photos to twitter.

Let me know if anyone has achieved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShareKit supports sharing urls and text with Twitter but not photos (yet).

There has been interest in getting a patch submitted to support this:
http://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues#issue/1

It's open source so anyone can submit an update to add photo support to Twitter (which would be awesome).

Comment: So,


Ive seen two ways of using TWITPIC with the iphone. The first being a service that uses the ASIHTTPREQUEST, but I found file conflicts with Reachability.h and Reachability.m


The second way of using TWITPIC is with the NSURLRequest.


Which would be the most efficient for ShareKIT?



Heres the source URL which I will be basing all my research and experiments.
http://maniacdev.com/2010/02/2-approaches-to-twitpic-integration/



Also, is twit pic the best service for this?